# OQL in VisualVM v1.4.4 - Get A Class's Field Names

Tags: javascript, jvm, visualvm, oql

I would like to [execute an OQL query](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visualvm/visualvm.java.net.backup/master/www/oqlhelp.html) in VisualVM (v1.4.4) to retrieve the (non-static) field names for an object.

The OQL documentation describes `heap.findClass(className)`. This returns an object which includes a `fields` property (an array of field names).

When I execute the following OQL...

`heap.findClass('java.io.ByteArrayInputStream').fields;`

... it returns an array of 4 field objects (`ByteArrayInputStream` [has 4 fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) - `buf`, `count`, `mark`, and `pos` - I am assuming these are what are being returned):

```
org.netbeans.lib.profiler.heap.HprofField@56de8c
org.netbeans.lib.profiler.heap.HprofField@56de95
org.netbeans.lib.profiler.heap.HprofField@56de9e
org.netbeans.lib.profiler.heap.HprofField@56dea7
```

If I then try to manipulate this array, for example to access each field's `name` and `signature` properties (as described in the OQL docs), I get no results. I can't even get the length of the array.  For example:

`heap.findClass('java.io.ByteArrayInputStream').fields.length;`

and:

`heap.findClass('java.io.ByteArrayInputStream').fields[0];`

Both of the above statements return `<no results>`.

**What am I doing wrong?** Probably something basic. I not very familiar with JavaScript - or with how data is displayed in VisualVM, for that matter.

Comment: hi! I too am new to OQL, are you trying the query with prefix _select_ say _**select heap.findClass('java.io.ByteArrayInputStream').fields;**_

Comment: No - I am not using the `select` syntax.  Just native JavaScript, exactly as shown above. (If I use the `select` syntax, I get the same results, by the way - I just tried it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [map()](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/visualvm/visualvm.java.net.backup/master/www/oqlhelp.html#map) function. The following OQL retrieves the field names of `ByteArrayInputStream` class:

```
select map(heap.findClass('java.io.ByteArrayInputStream').fields, 'it.name')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the very helpful answer from @Tomas - which I have accepted.

Based on his insight, I can also now do things like this in OQL - using a callback instead of an expression string:

```
map(heap.findClass('java.io.ByteArrayInputStream').fields, function (it) { 
  var res = ''; 
  res += toHtml(it.name) + " : " + toHtml(it.signature); 
  return res + "<br>"; 
});
```

The above example is trivial, but it opens up more possibilities.

His answer also made me realize where I was going wrong: OQL uses JavaScript *expression language* - not the exactly the same as JavaScript.